# Unable to use VNC when connected to OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, tcp, wireshark, vnc

When I try to VNC to a particular machine #1 (192.168.1.221) from within the network I am able to connect to it without issue. When I try to connect from outside the network from my OpenVPN VPN I am unable to do so, the connection will either take ~5 minutes to load and then constantly drop out, etc or I will get a The connection attempt timed out'. I have another machine #2 (192.168.1.220) which I can VNC to without issue.

This particular machine is a Windows 10 box with two NICs, IP address is static, running Ultra VNC Server 1.2.2.4. The VPN server is OpenVPN running on an Ubuntu Server box, the IP address of the box is 192.168.1.84 however the VPN puts you on 10.8.0.X/24.

I have noticed that,

- If I ping 192.168.1.220 I get between 10% - 30% packets dropped
- If I run wireshark while trying to connect via the VPN I get a range of [TCP Retransmission], [TCP Out-Of-Order] & [TCP DUP ACK ######] errors
- When looking at jobs I will set 192.168.1.84 has connected, 192.168.1.84 disconnected in a loop.

So far I have tried,

- Restarting the machine
- Change the IP from .221 to something else
- Ran a new wire and tried with the second NIC
- Updated WinVNC to the latest version
- Set the NIC to different speeds/duplex
- Used a different port to the default 5900
- Various VNC viewing clients
- If I telnet to it I get a rfb 003.008 response which I understand means it worked

I believe after some research it could be an MTU issue or a route table, but I'm just not sure. I made some adjustments to the MTU on my router and I was able to ping it with less drops but couldn't VNC on, I read something about VNC not liking MTU under 1500 (as I had to set mine under 1500) so what would I do about this? If it's a route table, is that on the machine or the vpn server?

King Regards,
Coldgate

Comment: Anybody at all able to help with this? Thanks

Comment: I am not a network engineer, but changing the MTU on your devices can be opening a can of worms attached to time-bomb. Unless you are **100% sure** all the MTUs match, you may have exactly the dropped packets that you are seeing. I would recommend setting the MTUs in all places you have changed back to their default value. This should be 1500. Then test if your setup works.